# Tomcat 7.0.5 parallel deployment

Tags: tomcat

Does anyone have documentation about Tomcat 7.0.5 parallel deployment? Particularly with Grails?

Google only seems to find the original Beta announcements.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation for tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) under "Naming" it is specified that you can specify which context version your application has by naming it warfile##{context-version}.war.
The context path will then be /warFile and it will be versioned context-version.

I have tried this and it works perfectly for me so far, and I can be logged in to two different versions of my application in two different browsers if one browser has an old session and the other one a new session.

It might be worth to remember that after a while you might end up with a lot of war-files and folders, so deleting old versions regularly might be a good idea...

Also, cited from the documentation:

> String comparisons are used to determine version order. If version is not specified, it is treated as the empty string. Therefore, foo.war will be treated as an earlier version than foo##11.war and foo##11.war will be treated as an earlier version than foo##2.war. If using a purely numerical versioning scheme it is recommended that zero padding is used so that foo##002.war is treated as an earlier version than foo##011.war.

Answer (score 0):

Here is *some* official documentation on it: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment.  I'll post more if I find any.

Comment: It still doesn't say _how_ to deploy in parallel etc. It's all a little vague at the moment.

Comment: If I recall correctly, normally a WAR's context path is the name of the war.  However, in tomcat/conf/context.xml you can specify which content root a war should have.  With parallel deployment you can have several wars deployed (each with a different war name) but give them the same context root.  When you've done that, I assume the parallel deployment will kick in automatically.